# communication between 2 view models: the content of one depends on the state of another

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I have 2 views and their view models: picker and editor.

The editor is empty in the beginning and waits for something to be picked using the picker.
The picker needs to communicate the picked entity to the editor to get it initialized.

Both views don't know anything about each other and should be orchestrated by the parent view where they both belongs.

The picker view contains a dropdown that has its "SelectedItem" property bound to the "Input" property of its view model.

The editor view model has the "Initialize" method that takes one parameter that should be coming from the Input property of the picker view model.

The question: how do I marry the Input property of the picker view model and the Initialize method of the editor view model?

Illustation:

`public class PickerViewModel {
public InputInfo Input { get; set; } }`

```
public class EditorViewModel { public void Initialize(InputInfo input) { /* blah-blah */ } }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [MVVM Light Toolkit Messenger](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/09/27/mvvm-light-toolkit-messenger-v2-beta.aspx) or [Prism Event Aggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx).

Comment: Is there a simpler way? Setting up an event aggregator for connecting 2 views looks like an overkill to me.

Comment: Basically I just need to translate the assignment of the Input property of the picker view model to a method call on the editor view model.

Comment: All that i write below - best solution for your problem, but if you want you can, of cource,  simply store in one ViewModel reference to another.
But you include `mvvm` tag in your question, so what you expected to see?

Comment: I ended up with a special event in the picker which is connected to the editor by the parent view.